# sysctl: unknown oid 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches' macos

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

When I try to set fs inotify max user watches on macOS, I get error

> sysctl: unknown oid 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches'

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=524288
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
```

Comment: why those "magic" values? How did you come up with 524288? Is there something special about that number?

Comment: @EricG Good question. Actually, I just copied the values from the another topic.